# Set index starting from the second row for a dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a toy dataset as follows:

```
0  start_date  end_date
1      2019      2021
```

Read the second row:

```
df.iloc[0]
```

Out:

```
0
start_date    2019
end_date      2021
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Read columns:

```
df.columns
```

Out:

```
Out[218]: Index(['start_date', 'end_date'], dtype='object', name=0)
```

How could I reset index `0` starting from the secode row? Thanks.

```
   start_date  end_date
0      2019      2021
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True` for default index and then remove (set to `None`) index and columns names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
print(df)
   start_date  end_date
0        2019      2021
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain why `df.iloc[0]` returns `0 start_date 2019 end_date      2021 Name: 1, dtype: object` in my question? I think it suppose to return first row of `df`.

Comment: @ahbon - yes, because there is only one `[]` it convert first row to Series, if use one element list like `df.iloc[[0]]` it return one row DataFrame